# Accessing real-time user location via last post or mobile location

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, geolocation, real-time, facebook-fql

I've built an app utilizing user's straight location; but I'd like access to the user's latest  location i.e. when a user posts from a mobile device they include an approx. location; how can we access that?  This would open a door to a huge "real-time" market.

Comment: please tell me the name of your app so that I can stay far FAR away from it ;-)

Comment: https://www.mknwebsolutions.com/fbmapfeed/ - Uses the user's manually set home location in order to show real-time status feeds via Google maps API.

Comment: yeah yeah, I get it. I just hate targeted marketing. Personal preference.

Comment: ha, yea don't worry this won't touch that.  I'm thinking more of an augmented reality based facebook.  Obviously very few friends actually include their realtime location with posts and such, but I'd like to play around with it and see what the capabilities are.

Comment: seems like a treat. I'll follow this question and see where it takes you. Sorry, I can't be of service.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exposed via the Graph API.

I can't be 100% sure, but I posted a status update via the mobile app, verified it had the location "Brooklyn" on it.  Then I used the API Explorer to drill down and look at that status update: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=781062048236 and there is no location information available.

You can also verify by [looking at the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/) that they just don't make it available.

Comment: That's correct, it's not provided in the code.  I'm hoping this message hits the API team.

Comment: @MichaelMikhjian if you want that to happen, I'd suggest going here: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: Yea, I've added it / linked it here. Thanks though!